# Copy only files between two times

Tags: find

I'm trying to copy pictures taken between two times, from one directory to another.

I’ve managed to list them using this command `find /mnt -type f -name "*.jpg" -newermt "2014-12-14 01:00:00" ! -newermt "2014-12-14 02:00:00"`

But when I added `-exec cp -pf {} /home/pi/box/pictures/ \;` to the end, my system locked up;

e.g. `find /mnt -type f -name "*.jpg" -newermt "2014-12-14 01:00:00" ! -newermt "2014-12-14 02:00:00 -exec cp -pf {} /home/pi/box/pictures/ \;"`

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the `-exec` between the quotes that were around the end time, that is not what you want. You should do:

`find /mnt -type f -name "*.jpg" -newermt "2014-12-14 01:00:00" ! -newermt "2014-12-14 02:00:00" -exec cp -pf {} /home/pi/box/pictures/ \;`

(all on one line)